# 2.8 - Moving objects too far from world origin makes the un-selectable

Tags: modeling, interface, shortcut

I must have pressed something weird cus all of a sudden there is this "invisible wall" surrounding my world origin, and if I drag my objects outside it, I can no longer select them unless I do it in the hierarchy. I can see it happening when I drag an object too far from the world origin this line appears as I go outside the "invisible wall", as you can see in the image, only half of my object is selectable:

[image]

Comment: How far from the world origin exactly ?

Comment: No idea what I had turned on, but pressing alt+b solved it